# Error at imread from OpenCV-3.1 using Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, opencv3.0

I use OpenCV for some of my image processing projects.
Normally I use Visual Studio (VS) for programming. I think this error is mostly from release and debug library setting in using VS.
Now I use Eclipse as programming editor.
I have "`undefined reference to symbol`" error at imread.
The whole complete error is as follow.

```
./src/HOGCPU.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'    Pedestrian_Detection            C/C++ Problem
```

I included all header files as

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

All libries and header files are linked properly at settings.
Libraries included in the Libraries Linker are

```
opencv_imgproc
opencv_highgui
opencv_ml
opencv_video
opencv_features2d
opencv_calib3d
opencv_objdetect
opencv_core
opencv_contrib
opencv_legacy
opencv_flann
```

Why I have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try linking opencv_imgcodecs (as imread has been moved there now).

Sidenote: 
Are you missing the objdetect-include in your sourcefile ?

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
```